# How can I efficiently move 40+GByte of mp3 data to my phone?

Tags: file-transfer, media-files, mp3, import

My entire music library is sitting on a server that I access through SSH (could be setup for HTTP) and I would like to copy it to my Xioami Mi A1 (running Nougat).

What would be the best way to accomplish this without using an SD card?  I installed Termux, and an rsync client, but:

- I don't know the location of where I should download too, and
- there seems to be a permission issue anywhere outside Termux's home directory ('whoami' reports my user credentials as "u0_a###")

I would like to transfer the music to the "proper" directory (not just the downloads directory).

With 50+G of unused storage space, I'd really like to make use of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default path for music is typically `/sdcard/Music`. Don't be fooled by the `sdcard` in the path, that's a relic of the past from a time where devices didn't feature their own external storage.

For Termux to work correctly in this regard, you have to manually grant read/write permissions to your "SD card" to Termux. Do that in the Settings app under the point of app permissions (exact naming may differ by manufacturer).

The user identifier is the one of the app, because on Android every app gets its own separate user to protect the data of each app.

I have no experience with `rsync` but I can imagine it will work, if you just switch into the `/sdcard/Music` directory and use `rsync` from there.

Termux should have all the tools for doing what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

File copying over SSH, with `scp`, is quite fast, depending on your network environment, and is more reliable than `adb push` and MTP.

In fact, copying over network is my primary choice for bunches of files.

Comment: Agreed.  But you neglected to address my only two points: permissions and proper location.